# Changing page using window.location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't really know what to title this. I am using jQuery so that when a user clicks a div, it transfers them to a page based off the div's class:

```
window.location = $(this).attr('class');
```

Say I'm connecting from the webserver (localhost). The first click may bring me to

```
localhost/info
```

If I click on about, it will bring me to

```
localhost/info/about
```

I was wondering how to get it to transfer me to

```
localhost/about
```

instead of

```
localhost/info/about
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `location` is an object. While assigning to it does work, it's better to assign to `location.href`.

Also, `class` is a bad choice of attribute to use for this, since it's very limiting. Instead, you should consider a data attribute:

```
<div data-href="/about"></div>
```

Note the `/` in the attribute value. That's what you need to make requests relative to the domain. Now you get there:

```
location.href = this.getAttribute("data-href");
```

PS. Every time someone writes `$(this).attr(...)`, a unicorn dies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an absolute path instead of a relative one. To do that you can prepend a `/` to the class.

```
window.location = "/" + $(this).attr('class');
```